# how to remove 1 clock delay for read data from the block ROM using Coregen in verilog??

Tags: module, verilog, rom

i am trying to read the data from blocked ROM using coregen by loading .coe file. But data will arrive after one clock delay when address initialized.
i want address and data in same clock cycle. module is given inline.

```
module pixel_read(Clk,output_pixel);
input Clk;
output [7:0] output_pixel;
reg [16:0] ADDR_IN;

initial      ADDR_IN = 65535;


 always @ (posedge Clk)begin
     if(ADDR_IN!=65536) begin
            ADDR_IN<= ADDR_IN+1;
        end
end

imageread MEM1(
.clka(Clk),
.addra(ADDR_IN),
.douta(output_pixel)
);
endmodule
```

how i remove one clock delay to read data?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do here but I guess it is not possible to remove one clock cycle delay on your read data due to its protocol. You may want to post `imageread` module to help you further.

Answer (score -1):

You don't actually want a synchronous RAM/ROM.  You want an asynchronous one - i.e. a look up table.  You can force that by using LUTs instead of BRAMs.  BRAMs are always synchronous.